# Drawing matrix with characters in C

Tags: c, matrix

My task is to draw matrix with asteriks, but the problem is that user enters the number of points and their coordinates and asteriks should only be drawn in their position. The total size of matrix is 20x20. And the coordinates are in range [0,19]. I just don't know how to save the input numbers. I am beginner, and I hope you could help.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int n, i, j, a, b;
        char m[20][20] = {{0}}, x = '*';
        printf("Enter the number of points: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("Enter the point %d", i + 1);
            scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
            m[a][b] = x;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                if (m[a][b])
                    printf("%c", m[a][b]);
                else
                    printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the output that your code provides?  What is the output you wish to get?

It is not clear from your question.

Comment: The matrix 20x 20 is actually a coordinate system and the user chooses the number of points and enters their coordinates (x,y). Asteriks should only be drawn at these points entered by user. @abelenky

Answer (score 1):

You should

- Initialize the array `m`.
- Use `i` and `j` instead of `a` and `b` to decide what character to print.
- Fix the indentation.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n,i,j,a,b;
    char m[20][20]={{0}},x='*'; /* add ={{0}} to initialize the array */
    printf("Enter the number of points: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter the point %d",i+1);
        scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
        m[a][b]=x;
    }
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        for(j=0;j<20;j++){
            if (m[i][j])
                printf("%c", m[i][j]);
            else printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed the code, but it doesn't give correct results for example for diamond shape it draws one additional point at the bottom and instead of one point on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable (or an array of variables) you have to initialize it to a certain value. Otherwise the value saved in that memory cell remains the same as before the allocation (often nonsense numbers that do not correspond to ascii characters).
You can initialize them manually or using library functions like `memset` or `bzero`.

Initialize the array manually:

```
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        m[i][j] = 0;
```

Initialize with memset:

```
memset(&m, 0, sizeof(char[20][20]));
```

Fixed code using memset:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, j, a, b;
    char m[20][20], x = '*';
    memset(&m, 0, sizeof(char[20][20]));

    printf("Enter the number of points: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the point %d\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        m[a][b] = x;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            if (m[i][j])
                printf("%c", m[i][j]);
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Fixed code using a for loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, j, a, b;
    char m[20][20], x = '*';

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            m[i][j] = 0;

    printf("Enter the number of points: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the point %d\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        m[a][b] = x;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            if (m[i][j])
                printf("%c", m[i][j]);
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
****                
*  *                
*  *                
*  *                
*  *                
****
```

Comment: It is correct; it is just that this matrix should function as a coordinate system so instead of m[a][b] it should be m[b][a]